How to align a Colorbar with a specific Range of Y-Values to the plot?
I'm currently working on my thesis and analyzing both measured and calculated voltage data. To highlight the difference between the calculated and maximum measured voltages, I would like to include a colorbar that visually represents these differences in the plots.
I've put together some LaTeX code to achieve this, but I'm relatively new to LaTeX and would appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Below is the relevant code I've developed so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                   
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,groupplots,colorbrewer,dateplot}

%   Style
\pgfplotsset{
    legend style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    legend cell align=left, 
    align=left, 
    draw=white!15!black
    },
    scaled ticks = false, 
    tick label style ={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/use comma,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=
    },
    plot coordinates/math parser=false,
    compat=newest,
    every axis legend/.append style={
        at={(0.5,1.03)}, 
        anchor=south},
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=1.5pt},
    }
 
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/layers/Bowpark/.define layer set={
        axis background,axis grid,main,axis ticks,axis lines,axis tick labels,
        axis descriptions,axis foreground
    }{/pgfplots/layers/standard},
}

\newcommand\pgfplotscale{0.80}
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.style={
        unbounded coords=jump,
        width=\pgfplotscale\textwidth,
        enlargelimits=false,
        no marks,
        legend image post style={line width=2.25pt},
        legend image post style={line join=round} 
    }
}
\pgfplotsset{with markers/.style={/pgfplots/every axis plot
post/.append style={mark=#1}}}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={line join=round},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Time},
            ylabel={Voltage drop in \si{\%}},
            grid=major,
            xmin=2024-07-28 00:00,  xmax=2024-07-28 24:00,
            ymin=-2.5,              ymax=5,
            xtick={2024-07-28 00:00,2024-07-28 02:00,2024-07-28 04:00,2024-07-28 06:00,2024-07-28 08:00,2024-07-28 10:00,2024-07-28 12:00,2024-07-28 14:00,2024-07-28 16:00,2024-07-28 18:00,2024-07-28 20:00,2024-07-28 22:00,2024-07-28 24:00},
            ytick={-2.5,-2.0,...,5},
            y tick label style={
                                    /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                    fixed,
                                    fixed zerofill,
                                    precision=1,
                                    /tikz/.cd
                                    },
            width=0.9\textwidth,
            date coordinates in=x,
            date ZERO = 2024-07-28,
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            xticklabel=\hour:\minute,
            legend columns=4,
            set layers=Bowpark,
            colorbar,
            colormap={mycolormap}{
                [1pt]
                RGB(0pt)=(152,78,163);
                RGB(823pt)=(152,78,163);  
                RGB(824pt)=(255,127,0);
                RGB(1000pt)=(255,127,0);
            },
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=4.71,
            colorbar style={
                ytick={0,3.8747,4.71},           % Ticks bei 0, 5 und 7
                yticklabels={\SI{0}{\%}, \SI{82.3}{\%}, \SI{100}{\%}},  % Beschriftung der Ticks in Prozent
            },
        ]
            \pgfplotsset{cycle list/Set1};  %index of colormap=3 of Set1
            
            \addplot+ [const plot] table [x=datetime, y=UL1_relativ, col sep=tab] {KVS_U_relativ.dat};
            \addlegendentry{L1}
    
            \addplot+ [const plot] table[x=datetime, y=UL2_relativ, col sep=tab] {KVS_U_relativ.dat};
            \addlegendentry{L2}

            \addplot+ [const plot] table[x=datetime, y=UL3_relativ, col sep=tab] {KVS_U_relativ.dat};
            \addlegendentry{L3}

            \addplot+ [densely dashed] [const plot] table[x=datetime, y=max_voltage_overall, col sep=tab] {KVS_U_relativ.dat};
            \addlegendentry{Measured data}

            \addplot+ coordinates {(2024-07-28 00:00, 4.71) (2024-07-28 24:00, 4.71)};
            \addlegendentry{Calculated data}

            \addplot+ [black] coordinates {(2024-07-28 00:00, 0.0) (2024-07-28 24:00, 0.0)};
            \addlegendentry{Reference voltage}

            \addplot+ coordinates {(2024-07-28 00:00, 3.5) (2024-07-28 24:00, 3.5)};
            \addlegendentry{Maximum allowed voltage range}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Voltage drop along the line between the transformer station and the cable distribution cabinet}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

This is the output of this code: 
I want a colorbar that visually aligns with the plot data, so that the start of the colorbar (0%) corresponds to the reference voltage (y=0) and the end (100%) aligns with the calculated data (y=4.71). Is there a better approach to my provided code?
The percentages used in the colorbar have been calculated externally, but I am interested in whether there is a way to dynamically adjust these values within the LaTeX code.
Additionally, I would appreciate any suggestions for improving the LaTeX code I have provided.
The data used for the plots:
\begin{filecontents}{KVS_U_relativ.dat}
datetime    UL1_relativ UL2_relativ UL3_relativ UL1L2L3min  UL1L2L3max  min_voltage_overall max_voltage_overall
2024-07-28 00:00    -0.388501062307589  -0.421351967609651  0.143283220279566   -0.421351967609651  0.143283220279566   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 00:10    -0.645029845634992  -0.352311039079223  0.166148174749803   -0.645029845634992  0.166148174749803   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 00:20    -0.62322749323569   -0.662174014989014  0.244483939485884   -0.662174014989014  0.244483939485884   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 00:30    -0.659769276208344  -0.550650749327974  0.202032463928981   -0.659769276208344  0.202032463928981   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 00:40    -0.656021730991907  -0.267684593554673  0.0582439028630644  -0.656021730991907  0.0582439028630644  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 00:50    -0.511101436656503  -0.342659595774886  0.0965255162158396  -0.511101436656503  0.0965255162158396  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:00    -0.496880357127316  -0.410303267632606  0.255844460467913   -0.496880357127316  0.255844460467913   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:10    -0.425094961080086  -0.411529794583121  0.144251240473769   -0.425094961080086  0.144251240473769   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:20    -0.442006719197519  -0.380619680123051  0.118907612257035   -0.442006719197519  0.118907612257035   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:30    -0.391103694626238  -0.375802653644641  0.0733296885440771  -0.391103694626238  0.0733296885440771  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:40    -0.438010231849351  -0.399042645778935  0.169525415771954   -0.438010231849351  0.169525415771954   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 01:50    -0.375412649054496  -0.364469255254751  -0.0260912672528479 -0.375412649054496  -0.0260912672528479 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:00    -0.313403104390697  -0.460737092169206  0.0243721982852385  -0.460737092169206  0.0243721982852385  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:10    -0.420902956788749  -0.403034096510091  0.153713509370856   -0.420902956788749  0.153713509370856   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:20    -0.520762913306494  -0.33455757269103   0.107557785093437   -0.520762913306494  0.107557785093437   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:30    -0.545514897928878  -0.399963322140762  0.16129524440589    -0.545514897928878  0.16129524440589    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:40    -0.43403913767982   -0.395410276307651  0.0892480093340309  -0.43403913767982   0.0892480093340309  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 02:50    -0.426099812899872  -0.428511022279965  0.147972129014295   -0.428511022279965  0.147972129014295   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:00    -0.301719627472186  -0.508565427138308  0.0744092946346919  -0.508565427138308  0.0744092946346919  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:10    -0.851509792362604  -0.53618016351531   0.141992247049094   -0.851509792362604  0.141992247049094   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:20    -0.819457306099614  -0.693044244852359  0.0156871631072697  -0.819457306099614  0.0156871631072697  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:30    -0.695554914759577  -0.422010901584602  0.107190476605457   -0.695554914759577  0.107190476605457   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:40    -0.757065801781642  -0.541593507866212  0.0553828173718962  -0.757065801781642  0.0553828173718962  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 03:50    -0.638896546895451  -0.649912965894872  0.0113552985570031  -0.649912965894872  0.0113552985570031  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:00    -0.863636363636366  -0.447021023957528  0.399016196132829   -0.863636363636366  0.399016196132829   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:10    -0.505479308171697  -0.679142375162789  0.0799074296443658  -0.679142375162789  0.0799074296443658  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:20    -0.633517398774941  -0.761912246920693  0.0178811297385062  -0.761912246920693  0.0178811297385062  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:30    -0.48628739453942   -0.686748459833497  0.0353018086729273  -0.686748459833497  0.0353018086729273  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:40    -0.245243757431635  -0.572002445201292  0.00785052598524238 -0.572002445201292  0.00785052598524238 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 04:50    -0.690780551399506  -0.553077531334512  0.0397145787417896  -0.690780551399506  0.0397145787417896  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:00    -0.885126202712294  -0.596530943130724  0.0196432780702471  -0.885126202712294  0.0196432780702471  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:10    -0.957993642565047  -0.689166925231721  -0.0816515443931132 -0.957993642565047  -0.0816515443931132 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:20    -0.840817468715294  -0.477591611151373  0.196575832069312   -0.840817468715294  0.196575832069312   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:30    -0.990519562980319  -0.549316086177509  0.1366012900748 -0.990519562980319  0.1366012900748 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:40    -1.06409565022952   -0.504776568569143  0.081286245580614   -1.06409565022952   0.081286245580614   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 05:50    -1.02205840458962   -0.408377421188399  -0.0913249990168397 -1.02205840458962   -0.0913249990168397 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:00    -0.841371989068307  -0.101544616165727  0.0603218037093622  -0.841371989068307  0.0603218037093622  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:10    -0.953866432337436  -0.0267277754165796 0.108961539639685   -0.953866432337436  0.108961539639685   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:20    -0.698493763135155  -0.256800622971187  -0.348302625598729  -0.698493763135155  -0.256800622971187  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:30    -0.683178990297817  -0.247421077857757  -0.350716747695323  -0.683178990297817  -0.247421077857757  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:40    -0.468609243988638  -0.324898361250681  -0.250318292656615  -0.468609243988638  -0.250318292656615  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 06:50    -0.819088937093282  -0.137144538229583  -0.241226363707114  -0.819088937093282  -0.137144538229583  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:00    -0.565028142914803  -0.843942149476051  0.088682395895523   -0.843942149476051  0.088682395895523   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:10    -0.277700518026636  -1.13186927560367   0.141560892829307   -1.13186927560367   0.141560892829307   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:20    -0.527456867149512  -0.618721193910776  -0.0683970840331671 -0.618721193910776  -0.0683970840331671 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:30    -0.711473699188925  -0.583166919157141  -0.0382514365778297 -0.711473699188925  -0.0382514365778297 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:40    -0.73982048283926   -0.0999258061610941 -0.511730368668728  -0.73982048283926   -0.0999258061610941 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 07:50    -0.56343735585358   0.0331108741270736  -0.485247196945948  -0.56343735585358   0.0331108741270736  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:00    -0.370962639381844  0.0229047551135952  -0.546910774919862  -0.546910774919862  0.0229047551135952  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:10    0.066890213179982   0.0875224222046889  -1.06833439516671   -1.06833439516671   0.0875224222046889  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:20    -0.260871833668119  0.262936383279677   -0.966967019053144  -0.966967019053144  0.262936383279677   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:30    -0.296739784046651  0.172218839697313   -1.1347881453537    -1.1347881453537    0.172218839697313   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:40    0.304859486305231   0.487692701531195   -1.73370529613127   -1.73370529613127   0.487692701531195   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 08:50    0.386224654007084   0.322279410167869   -1.32193014825587   -1.32193014825587   0.386224654007084   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:00    0.419624027264742   0.0792015788380285  -1.39762766541693   -1.39762766541693   0.419624027264742   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:10    1.13759409848795    0.950294919112826   -1.81240996178498   -1.81240996178498   1.13759409848795    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:20    1.11768204898319    0.974618590074727   -1.71181379877893   -1.71181379877893   1.11768204898319    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:30    1.24533001245331    0.904772967810219   -1.71883138406175   -1.71883138406175   1.24533001245331    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:40    2.09530640993509    1.59609584341951    -1.48441109292896   -1.48441109292896   2.09530640993509    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 09:50    1.94873921627075    1.06477947550232    -1.26276357923992   -1.26276357923992   1.94873921627075    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:00    1.18118057594969    0.406171040263548   -1.6635309144889    -1.6635309144889    1.18118057594969    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:10    2.37573067857051    1.10994295168991    -1.68373838224829   -1.68373838224829   2.37573067857051    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:20    1.45888708993152    0.482603379519819   -1.73453377651183   -1.73453377651183   1.45888708993152    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:30    2.42502343017807    1.16661758847065    -1.97555681675411   -1.97555681675411   2.42502343017807    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:40    2.35867140666388    1.40482983537218    -1.88382431545691   -1.88382431545691   2.35867140666388    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 10:50    3.0519494687234 1.93297062023938    -1.73221075739032   -1.73221075739032   3.0519494687234 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:00    2.41390591263004    1.1211415892628 -2.28477585673649   -2.28477585673649   2.41390591263004    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:10    1.78558204573076    0.808016776877074   -2.2749817270544    -2.2749817270544    1.78558204573076    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:20    1.53761621517905    1.06992308026594    -1.49021313614616   -1.49021313614616   1.53761621517905    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:30    2.82963143127666    1.04723611123148    -0.575985437839954  -0.575985437839954  2.82963143127666    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:40    3.01204036272731    2.10809617972472    -1.57928203442325   -1.57928203442325   3.01204036272731    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 11:50    1.6270093955894 1.36911754543569    -0.657539454527389  -0.657539454527389  1.6270093955894 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:00    0.865497379706692   1.25937950626451    -0.441799501625972  -0.441799501625972  1.25937950626451    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:10    1.12338562188039    1.5068825419926 -0.164259833919866  -0.164259833919866  1.5068825419926 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:20    2.64147514096666    2.56245276908129    0.485189409650233   0.485189409650233   2.64147514096666    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:30    3.22713284655105    2.0116147835525 0.0998875724293136  0.0998875724293136  3.22713284655105    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:40    2.88087014036893    2.58087058549485    0.470180862041425   0.470180862041425   2.88087014036893    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 12:50    3.30162597411574    2.62385645277361    0.296438850317782   0.296438850317782   3.30162597411574    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:00    3.4233774324453 2.54742734419811    0.110595096662713   0.110595096662713   3.4233774324453 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:10    3.79140385344501    2.40768672141221    0.0602845430431653  0.0602845430431653  3.79140385344501    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:20    3.72006829276663    2.23159193747429    -0.257968700369993  -0.257968700369993  3.72006829276663    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:30    1.96689646846802    0.77325909128072    -0.196296200635371  -0.196296200635371  1.96689646846802    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:40    2.01136050199973    1.07422420722769    -0.304938367181928  -0.304938367181928  2.01136050199973    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 13:50    3.87474530831098    2.70478407078132    0.215825489675492   0.215825489675492   3.87474530831098    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:00    0.75326249027805    0.424032207582847   -0.612525897234628  -0.612525897234628  0.75326249027805    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:10    -0.0938934782795942 -0.142595758205699  -0.781169389509895  -0.781169389509895  -0.0938934782795942 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:20    1.99460037170731    1.06590807828084    -0.0815219723168559 -0.0815219723168559 1.99460037170731    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:30    1.71434215555335    1.1395095694805 -0.240010991558826  -0.240010991558826  1.71434215555335    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:40    1.53494476085914    1.13812859141611    -0.369616891877422  -0.369616891877422  1.53494476085914    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 14:50    2.40697416281015    2.06160076734521    -0.428803659124555  -0.428803659124555  2.40697416281015    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:00    0.804426273067804   0.684623777839577   -0.672635179975933  -0.672635179975933  0.804426273067804   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:10    1.22213678481371    1.21271095983779    -0.457118820848046  -0.457118820848046  1.22213678481371    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:20    0.839850405690457   0.483147904351333   -0.615782107869522  -0.615782107869522  0.839850405690457   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:30    1.17556311110536    0.697482530705562   -0.295566502463063  -0.295566502463063  1.17556311110536    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:40    1.20546246706503    0.989163441756191   -0.357390148762049  -0.357390148762049  1.20546246706503    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 15:50    3.17577231733741    1.91162015470745    -0.0132653803526894 -0.0132653803526894 3.17577231733741    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:00    3.17342699276137    2.22600396798247    0.136965193720151   0.136965193720151   3.17342699276137    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:10    0.828283089327941   0.303805083471187   -0.332724341751744  -0.332724341751744  0.828283089327941   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:20    2.03894645829839    1.27819516611389    0.0292042277414417  0.0292042277414417  2.03894645829839    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:30    2.36712895167541    1.42754653595503    0.00558988317145293 0.00558988317145293 2.36712895167541    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:40    2.05749438884748    1.61096954670266    -0.272351776955504  -0.272351776955504  2.05749438884748    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 16:50    2.62632692737816    1.78467140746847    0.0373896039710386  0.0373896039710386  2.62632692737816    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:00    2.42823419946241    1.769193103626  0.104465805719389   0.104465805719389   2.42823419946241    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:10    2.06094116025906    1.16006491554967    0.171808759669623   0.171808759669623   2.06094116025906    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:20    2.13392009664337    1.61179978572443    -0.0964548535307252 -0.0964548535307252 2.13392009664337    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:30    1.03121769334251    0.377207027962512   -0.457310496570174  -0.457310496570174  1.03121769334251    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:40    1.24490503859163    0.178614676677169   -1.51397767553787   -1.51397767553787   1.24490503859163    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 17:50    1.27154649186696    0.0151433207139062  -0.420189863567988  -0.420189863567988  1.27154649186696    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:00    1.68117500173408    1.07225865539975    -0.349961547434907  -0.349961547434907  1.68117500173408    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:10    1.46513151898899    0.876699768174127   -0.357955971848301  -0.357955971848301  1.46513151898899    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:20    1.11949744905622    -0.139142794757963  -0.0153977758768131 -0.139142794757963  1.11949744905622    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:30    0.938390552093638   0.00388693342547874 -0.115190971098711  -0.115190971098711  0.938390552093638   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:40    0.779955110497221   0.36858739741128    -0.0877823342355422 -0.0877823342355422 0.779955110497221   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 18:50    0.624722069915329   0.335529999569295   -0.350596099510714  -0.350596099510714  0.624722069915329   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:00    0.731177980260767   0.282351121024194   -0.786792542014558  -0.786792542014558  0.731177980260767   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:10    0.869311000094575   0.0995567151433452  -1.55422854838571   -1.55422854838571   0.869311000094575   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:20    0.59728576834428    0.327170618189321   -0.836162751267344  -0.836162751267344  0.59728576834428    -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:30    0.273720667414357   -0.497877267464297  -0.375440370983093  -0.497877267464297  0.273720667414357   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:40    0.123991762484987   0.139147560636221   -0.486380489976979  -0.486380489976979  0.139147560636221   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 19:50    0.155799743082308   -0.0406989833913518 -0.467370607581796  -0.467370607581796  0.155799743082308   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:00    0.129026671285071   0.0354116824003992  -0.505342562703903  -0.505342562703903  0.129026671285071   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:10    -0.068227052678238  -0.136048526863097  -0.463355909303487  -0.463355909303487  -0.068227052678238  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:20    -0.921384985287343  0.359617273746204   -0.576755125511252  -0.921384985287343  0.359617273746204   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:30    -0.652987907792046  0.195080173193118   -0.772085668240796  -0.772085668240796  0.195080173193118   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:40    -0.519578936365739  -0.218142313959813  -0.38011594404137   -0.519578936365739  -0.218142313959813  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 20:50    -0.984507964215575  0.117916831648701   -0.220293028833618  -0.984507964215575  0.117916831648701   -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:00    -0.473528243668475  -0.0901006777137892 -0.340646575914583  -0.473528243668475  -0.0901006777137892 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:10    -0.483894233921556  -0.392425618103087  0.0056645373816 -0.483894233921556  0.0056645373816 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:20    -0.472474013929236  -0.170797550300095  -0.285604653393678  -0.472474013929236  -0.170797550300095  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:30    -0.591566033449253  -0.58725234835495   -0.176438298873405  -0.591566033449253  -0.176438298873405  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:40    -0.546079864180149  -0.38516629401899   -0.303297432227201  -0.546079864180149  -0.303297432227201  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 21:50    -0.626423690205014  -0.0126751575653339 -0.435373080231782  -0.626423690205014  -0.0126751575653339 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:00    -0.684175485317828  -0.228487048759918  -0.252783235101506  -0.684175485317828  -0.228487048759918  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:10    -0.435102663196363  -0.458316386997459  -0.314969573327628  -0.458316386997459  -0.314969573327628  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:20    -0.414093206064003  -0.740228415841149  -0.215082907466257  -0.740228415841149  -0.215082907466257  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:30    -0.483965091330307  -0.335911427995828  -0.188897877085192  -0.483965091330307  -0.188897877085192  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:40    -0.54519734298667   -0.297086970238725  -0.238941306212481  -0.54519734298667   -0.238941306212481  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 22:50    -0.798859777234262  -0.243907788817976  -0.105158460655408  -0.798859777234262  -0.105158460655408  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:00    -0.545588034871913  -0.754369421723211  0.0438033579654107  -0.754369421723211  0.0438033579654107  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:10    -0.572549295526903  -0.541871056626619  0.0845364075968913  -0.572549295526903  0.0845364075968913  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:20    -0.531157283034089  -0.290640501737294  0.00916394293919431 -0.531157283034089  0.00916394293919431 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:30    -0.551750463045297  -0.352242190305996  -0.0712573686597273 -0.551750463045297  -0.0712573686597273 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:40    -0.518665890550196  -0.343514591789429  -0.0553743391851214 -0.518665890550196  -0.0553743391851214 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-28 23:50    -0.496667159133357  -0.345482288072407  0.0147196979864317  -0.496667159133357  0.0147196979864317  -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
2024-07-29 00:00    -0.302752055162381  -0.360879768691191  -0.0220113164062119 -0.360879768691191  -0.0220113164062119 -2.28477585673649   3.87474530831098
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1, xmax=1,
ymin=-2.5, ymax=5,
colormap={mycolormap}{color(0)=(violet) color(823)=(violet) color(824)=(orange) color(1000)=(orange)},
colorbar,
colorbar shift/.style={
  at=(current axis.right of origin),
  anchor=south west, 
  xshift=0.3cm,
  height=101.7pt, %set manually from parent axis coordinate
},
point meta min=0, point meta max=100,
colorbar style={ytick={0,82.3,100}},
]
\path let \p1=(axis direction cs:0,4.71) in (0,0) node {\y1}; %show height
\addplot[orange, thick] coordinates {(-1, 4.71) (1, 4.71)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


